# How can I achieve something similar to a pointer to a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pointers

Is there a concept like a pointer to a string in javascript? Or how would this be done?

```
let s1 = "hi";
let s2 = "bye";

// I want to write my code like this [,].forEach();
// This is the bit where I want s1 and s2 in the [,] array to actually be pointers to a string
[s1,s2].forEach(s => {if(s.length < 3) s += "*";});

// I want console.log(s1) === "hi*"
// I want console.log(s2) === "bye" (unchanged)
```

Comment: This would only work with global variables and you'd have an array with names of variables as string: `["s1","s1"].forEach(s => {if (window[s].length < 3) window[s] += "*";});`

Comment: I need to do this with local variables.

Comment: Than your only option is objects as shown in the answers below. Or use of `eval(s)`: `["s1","s1"].forEach(s => {let n = eval(s); if (n.length < 3) eval(s + ` += "*"`;});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution myself.

Could anyone comment if this is good practice or not?

It uses the new thing in ES6 where you can assign things `[s1, s2] =`

```
let s1 = "hi", s2 = "bye";
[s1, s2] = [s1, s2].map(s => s + (s.length < 3 ? "*" : ""));
```

Comment: That's clever, but it's hard to read. Now I'm curious what is a practical use of this?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript does not have pointers.

But you can wrap a value in an object and pass references to that object around.

```js
let s1 = { value: "hi" };
let s2 = { value: "bye" };

[s1,s2].forEach(s => {
  if(s.value.length < 3) s.value += "*";
});

console.log(s1.value)
console.log(s2.value)
```

That's probably the closest you're going to get to this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reassign individual identifiers unless you specifically reference the identifier. So given

```
let s1 = "hi";
```

The only way to make `console.log(s1)` show something else would be to have a line of code that does

```
s1 = // something else
```

And strings are immutable, of course - for a string, you'd have to reassign it, since you can't mutate it.

I suppose you could put the strings into an array or an object, then examine that instead:

```js
const strings = {
  s1: 'hi',
  s2: 'bye',
};
for (const [key, str] of Object.entries(strings)) {
  if (str.length < 3) {
    strings[key] += '*';
  }
}
console.log(strings.s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is no "pointers", and the only way access local variables is through evil function the `eval()`:

```js
{
  let s1 = "hi";
  let s2 = "bye";
  ["s1","s1"].forEach(s => {
    let n = eval(s);
    if (n.length < 3)
      eval(s + ' += "*"');
  });
  
  console.log(s1,s2);
}
```

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. Please interpret this answer purely as an academic curiosity. If code like this is ever deployed to production, the amount of suffering in the world will assuredly increase.

Comment: Why this function exists then? Yes, this particular code will break the entire internet, do not click `run code snippet` button!...jeez paranoid much?

Comment: [MDN includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) this warning: _"Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval(). See Never use eval()!, below."_ Why it exists is mostly historical at this point. And I want to be sure that some new developer that finds this answer a month doesn't think this is the right to write their JS code.